# jQuery dropdown menu in same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show drop down menu on mouseover. Now I am using 2 `divs` and use slideup to show another div for sub menu; I want to show sub menu using 1 div on mouseover. How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#flip").mouseover(function () {
                $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
            });
            $("#flip").mouseleave(function () {
                $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #flip {
            padding: 1px;
            text-align: left;
            border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
        }
        #panel {
            padding: 1px;
            text-align: left;
            border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
            padding: 5px;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="flip">
        <ul>Home</ul>
    </div>
    <div id="panel">
        <ul><a href="#">Sub</a>
            </br>
            <a href="#">Sub</a>
            </br>
            <a href="#">Sub</a>
            <ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

`

Comment: Where are the `<li>`s

Comment: I removes <li> those does not work . I need all in same div i mean using 1st div

Comment: please help me about my code

Answer (score 2):

A nested unordered list would work, something like this:

```
<ul id="flip">
    <li>Home
        <ul id="panel">
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In CSS, all you would need is to hide your sub-menu:

```
#panel {
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery is the same as you had it.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/kaizora/23uuL/

PS: If you are using a `<ul>` tag, in valid HTML, there should be nothing else but `<li>` tags inside.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$("#flip").mouseover(function () {
      $("#panel").slideDown("slow");

      $("#panel").mouseleave(function () {
          $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
      });
});
```

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/vWGsC/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to you cold also use pure CSS.

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">second dropdown</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

This would be the html from something I have saved some time ago.

Try it out! :)

http://jsfiddle.net/patrickhaede/dqxm4/

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/player889/x23CG/) Background color is for clearly view for user.

> ```
>   var temp = $('#flip ul li:eq(0)').nextAll();
>     temp.hide();
>     $('#flip ul').mouseenter(function(event) {
>         temp.slideDown("slow");
>     });
>     $('#flip ul').mouseleave(function() {
>         temp.slideUp("slow");
>     });
> ```

```
#flip li , #flip ul { list-style-type: none; background-color: yellow;}
```

> - Home
> - Sub
> - Sub
> - Sub